# Learner Question: How would I associate a button within a message bar (Fabric UI) with a function?

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I'm using a message bar from MS Fabric and am looking at ways to dismiss this message bar.
Here's the current code:

```
public ChangeWarn = (p: IWarnProps) => (
    <MessageBar
    messageBarType={MessageBarType.warning}
    isMultiline={true}
    dismissButtonAriaLabel="Close"
    onDismiss={() => this._onWarnDismiss()}
    overflowButtonAriaLabel="See more"
    truncated={true}
    actions={
      <div>
        <MessageBarButton>OK</MessageBarButton>
      </div>
  }
> Warning.
</MessageBar>

)

public _onWarnDismiss() {
  this.setState({
    ClickCounter: 0
  });
}
```

The onDismiss works but I want the button to dismiss the bar also. My JS basics are letting me down so if anyone could advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a click handler to your Button like this:

```
<MessageBarButton onClick={() => this._onWarnDismiss()}>OK</MessageBarButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to dismiss the message bar on the button click, you can simply not render it anymore:

```
public ChangeWarn = (p: IWarnProps) => (
    {this.state.showMessagebar && 
    <MessageBar
    messageBarType={MessageBarType.warning}
    isMultiline={true}
    dismissButtonAriaLabel="Close"
    onDismiss={() => this._onWarnDismiss()}
    overflowButtonAriaLabel="See more"
    truncated={true}
    actions={
      <div>
        <MessageBarButton onClick={() => this._dismissWarning()}>OK</MessageBarButton>
      </div>
  }
> Warning.
</MessageBar>}
)

public _onWarnDismiss() {
  this.setState({
    ClickCounter: 0
  });
}

public _dismissWarning() {
  this.setState({
    ClickCounter: ,
    showMessagebar: false,
  });
}
```

I hope that will help you,

greetings Joe!

For more SharePoint development related information look [here](https://www.smarterbusiness.at/smarter-blog)